# rsyslog adding year and changing directory for logs file

Tags: rsyslog

I allready have template in rsyslog.conf file changing directory to store log files but now we must add year to every log msg in this file.

```
$template TmplAuth, "/home/someuser/logs/%HOSTNAME%/%HOSTNAME%.log"
*.* ?TmplAuth
```

I do have line that is adding year to every message and it works:

```
$template TmplAuth,"%$Year% %timegenerated% %syslogtag%%msg:::drop-last-lf%\n"
```

but how can I use both options (changing log path and adding year to every message in log file) together in single template - is it possible ?

If you know solution please let me know.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do this inside a template, but inside the action:

```
$template TmplData,"%$Year% %timegenerated% %syslogtag%%msg:::drop-last-lf%\n"
action(type="omfile" dynafile="TmplAuth" template="TmplData")
```

and in [obsolete legacy format](https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/conf_formats.html) you could use:

```
*.* ?TmplAuth;TmplData
```

Full details can be found in the [omfile documentation](https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/modules/omfile.html).

Comment: Great Rainer Gerhards - thanks a lot, it works perfect